# My code is infinitely looping and I'm not sure why

Tags: python

My code is just a simple prime factorization calculator.
I'm not sure why it's infinitely looping. I'm pretty new to Python and not entirely sure on how the while loop works.

````
def print_prime_factors(number):
  x = 2 
  while x < number:
    if number % x == 0:
      y = number/x
      print(str(x)+",")
      y = number
      if x > y:
        break

      x = x + 1
      

print_prime_factors(100)
# Should print 2,2,5,5
# DO NOT DELETE THIS COMMENT```
````

Comment: Think carefully about where you are incrementing the loop counter.

Comment: This is not the prime factors of *number*, it's all the divisors of *number*. The prime factors of 100 are 2² * 5². When you find a factor like x = 2 or 5, you need to test *repeatedly* whether number is divisible by it, and store the quotient between iterations. (You should be using quotient inside your loop, not *number*). Not just test divisibility-by-x once then increment x, like you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has an indentation error.

This line:

```py
x = x + 1
```

should be shifted over one indent. You're only incrementing `x` whenever it is a factor of the number, which means that the program will enter an infinite loop by repeatedly checking whether `number` is divisible by a non-factor of number.

Answer (score 1):

after the first iteration x changes and the if statements is never true again, which makes x never changes again. Seens to be just indentation problem.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The first bug is, as others have said, that your line `x = x + 1` that increments candidate x should be unindented one level, so it's under the while-loop.

(2) But you also have a bug with what you're doing with quotient y, it's mystifying.
When you identify that x is a factor of `number`, just print x. You compute the quotient `y = number/x`, silently throw it away, then assign `y = number`, which again gets thrown away. You could have just directly tested `if x > number: ... break`.

- but even that is roundabout. Your while-loop that starts x at 2, increments x by +1, and stops when x > `number`, is really **just a for-loop in disguise**: `for x in range(2, number+1): ...`
- But you can show we strictly only need to do:

  - `for x in range(2, ceil(sqrt(number)+1): ...` where we use `math.sqrt`, `math.ceil`
- ...really you need to store the quotient between iterations, and when it gets to 1 you know you can terminate early; you've found all the divisors of `number`